# C++ Zero-out a struct array?

Tags: c++

```
struct OBJECT
{
unsigned int Var1;
std::string Str1;
...
bool YesNo;
};

OBJECT Obj[ 327 ];
```

I am confused about how to zero-out Obj. It has several different type of elements. Do I have to set all of its member to 0?
Like... `Obj[0].Str = "";`
? So the question is, what is the proper way of doing it?

My attempt:

```
::memset( &Obj, 0, sizeof( Obj ) );
```

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly...

Oh and are there any faster way to zero-out an array?

Comment: sizeof( TYPE ) * 327 not object itself

Comment: Provide the correct default constructor.

Comment: @DenisErmolin Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that many of your objects don't have trivial copy/default constructor. A `memset` is not the way.

Comment: @Jon NO! `std::string` will panic if you 0 it out!

Comment: Ah you have std::string so it undefined behaviour to zero it with memset

Comment: Fudgee, what should I do? :(

Comment: What you are trying to do is C, not C++, applied to C++. As soon as you have a non-POD, zeroing-out is going to blow up in your face! Also, this whole typedef thing is very much C and utterly unnecessary in C++. Just call your class/struct `OBJECT`, no need for `OBJECT_STRUCT`.

Comment: @MichaelWild ohh okay. No more typedef struct crap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't do it this way, because you have non trivial members in your struct (e.g. `std::string`). You can do this if all your members are only simple data types, like `int`, `char`, `double` or pointers.

The correct way for this type of struct is to define a constructor, which initializes all members properly

```
struct OBJECT {
    OBJECT() : Var1(0), YesNo(false), ... {}

    unsigned int Var1;
    std::string Str1;
    ...
    bool YesNo;
};
```

Comment: There's a drawback with the idea though: upon adding a new member, it is easy to forget to update the constructors, whilst the *memset/std∷fill* way don't need to be updated.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yes, you're right as long as you have only trivial members. With more complex members though, `memset` might even be dangerous, because it stomps over member's memory. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2099692/1741542 for a discussion about uninitialized member variables.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thank you for the advice; I tried, and I've to say there's doesn't seem to be good a method to definitely find unitialized variables. `-Weffc++` option gives hundreds wrong warnings, valgrind is only useful in runtime whilst I'm working with app whose runtime is in embedded device. Perhaps cppcheck can be useful for this — not sure, I didn't try that specific problem.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I haven't tried these myself, so cannot really comment. A quick check shows, neither `-Weffc++` nor cppcheck seem very reliable. `-Weffc++` complains even when there's a default constructor for a non POD type, and it doesn't complain at all, when there's no constructor defined. cppcheck doesn't show any warning at all. Maybe newer versions are better.

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" way is to add a constructor method for your struct that initialises any member variables that don't have constructors of their own, e.g.:

```
OBJECT_STRUCT()
: Var1(0)
, YesNo(false)
{
}
```

In that example you'll note that `Str1` was not initialised; this is because `std::string` has its own constructor that initialises it.

Answer (score 3):

Either provide a custom default constructor or use the compiler defined default constructor:

```
std::fill(std::begin(Obj), std::end(Obj), OBJECT());
```

Note that the `fill` approach fill only work if you use the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your declaration to

```
struct OBJECT
{
    unsigned int Var1;
    std::string Str1;
    ...
    bool YesNo;

   OBJECT()
   : Var1()
   , Str1()
   , ...
   , YesNo(false)
   {
       // Do Nothing
   }
};
```

The array - which you should use over `std::array` or `std::vector` - will initialise the objects.