# Why I can use class Variable without initialize it c++

Tags: c++, initialization

I have the next code (make it small & simple),

Why did I get the `speed +=` working, although the `speed` wasn't initialized at all?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle {

  protected:
     int speed;

     public:
         virtual void repair(int j) {
             cout << "Vehicle " << j << endl;

             if (repair())
             {
                 speed += j;
                 cout << "Speed:" << speed;
             }
        }
        int repair(){ cout << "Vehicle repair " << endl; return 1; }
};

void main() { 
    Vehicle v; //Car c; CityCar cc;
    Vehicle * vp; //Car * cp;

    vp = &v; 
    vp->repair(1);
}
```

Comment: Speed just takes a junk value, so it might work but please initialize the variable first. It prevents errors.

Comment: The question is why?
if I will do:
int i;
i++;
I will get an error

Comment: ***if I will do: int i; i++; I will get an error*** That should be a warning not an error unless you have enabled treat warnings as errors.

Comment: If you can do `void main()` then you can use uninitialized variables.  BTW, the `main` function returns `int`.  Always.

Comment: the point is that I added the int i; i++; and I got error, but without it the speed is still get the junk value, what is the explanation for this?

Comment: I just did that added `int i; i++;` with Visual Studio 2013 and got `warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'i' used` which is a warning not an error. I do not have treat warnings as errors enabled.

Comment: Error should not come. `gcc` also warning with -Wall. Else nothing

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Off topic. In GCC I like `-pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Werror` If you're gonna see 'em, you might as well fix 'em.

Comment: It's likely that the compiler doesn't know that `speed` is uninitialized at that point. Maybe it was initialized in another function, or even by a derived class. Since the compiler can't know, it assumes you know what you're doing. In the case of `int i; i++;`, it's pretty obvious that i is not initialized when you increment it.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `vp = &v; vp->repair(1);` can be written better as `v.repair(1);`. There's no need for a pointer here.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can always use uninitialized variables, at most you'll get a warning. Except if you set a "warning as errors" option, in which case you'll get an error, obviously.

Different compilers do different things, so in your case, depending on the compiler and compiler options, you can get a warning, or not.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099692/easy-way-find-uninitialized-member-variables).

Comment: In the case of int i; i++; I get error, but with speed variable it does works, how can it be?@Ilya

Comment: Did you try to generate other warnings, such as "unused variable" ? What happens if you add an unused var in main() ?

Comment: @AlexZemtzov Would you mind improving your question and show your mysterious `int i; i++;` case in it please? Post [MCVE]s

Comment: @AlexZemtzov And how comes that the compiler accepts a `void` return for `main()` ? That's strange.

Comment: Maybe the #pragma is used to turn C4700 into an error. `#pragma warning(  error : 4700 )`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in fact by creating an object pointer
and then carry out an assignment operator on it 
you actually initialized it in junk value

try this:

```
Int x,*a;     
a=&x;
cout<<*a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Speed is a type of int, and int is a built-in type.If an object is of built-in type, then value-initializing it sets it to zero, and default-initializing it gives it an undefined value.
In your case, speed has an undefined value. Adding this constructor with constructor initializer in public section should work for you:

Vehicle() : speed{0} {}