# stumbling upon a non-trivial bool scenario in C++

Tags: c++, cppcheck, false-positive

When Cppcheck runs over this code,<sup>[1]</sup> it complains about an **error**:

```
void bool_express(bool aPre, bool aX, bool aPost)
{
    bool x;
    const bool pre = aPre;
    if (pre) {
        x = aX;
    }
    const bool post = aPost;

    // error checking passage of the original code:
    if ( !pre || !x || !post ) {
        if ( !pre ) {
            trace("pre failed");
        } else if ( !x ) {       // <-- HERE Cppcheck complains
            trace("x failed");
        } else {
            trace("post failed");
        }
    } else {
        // success passage of the original code:
        trace("ok");
    }
}
```

This is the message, that makes me nervous:

```
Id: uninitvar
Summary: Uninitialized variable: x
Message: Uninitialized variable: x
```

I think it's a false positive, but I admit that this may not be obvious. Nevertheless I don't want to touch that code, because it's old and a lot heavier than this extracted version.

Have you ever experienced situations like this? How to deal with it?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This code is reduced to its bones, the original code establishes a precondition (`pre`), does something (`x`), then forces a postcondition (`post`), after that, some error conditions are checked. I transformed the runtime-results of the functions that are called and then stored in `pre`, `x`, and `post` into the 3 arguments of my test case.

Comment: We're using Klockworks for static code analysis, and it shows the flow in which `x` is used uninitialized, if Cppcheck has this option post it and maybe they see something everyone else is missing, although it looks like a false positive to me

Comment: Did you make sure the reduced version still produces the CppCheck warning?

Comment: How about you just initialize `x` to false? I cannot imagine a realistic scenario in which that would blow up.

Comment: @nwp Finally you are right ;) As to check if the bug has been fixed in Cppcheck, I have (after preparing the question) a test project, so I will probably better initialize may original "x" and schedule a meta check for Cppcheck 1.76.

Comment: @nwp concerning *`Did you make sure the reduced version still produces the CppCheck warning`*, yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

The static analysis appears to be complaining because if `pre` is false, then `x` is never set.

Your code is structured such that the value of `x` is never accessed if `pre` *is* false - I'd argue that the static analyser isn't giving a useful output in this case.

Enumerating the various cases we have (so we can be reasonably sure that it's cppcheck and not us!):

1. The first statement in which `x` is accessed is in the line `if ( !pre || !x || !post )` - due to [short-circuiting evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): `if( A || B || C )` doesn't evaluate `B` or `C` if `A` is true; hence we never try to read an uninitialised `x` (since `x` is only uninitialised if `pre` is false, in which case we stopped evaluated the expression!)
2. The second usage is in

   `if ( !pre ) {
      trace("pre failed");
   } else if ( !x ) {       // <-- HERE Cppcheck complains`

   Again, we can only hit the offending line if `pre` was true (in which case `x` is properly initialised).

From this, we can conclude that either:

1. The actual code mistakenly tries to read `x` in some condition even is `pre` is false, and you've missed it when building the example (sometimes the logical flow of a program can be a bit obtuse)
2. The static analyser is lazy and spots the line `else if( !x )` and can't determine if this line is reachable with an uninitialised value.

From the code you've provided, you shouldn't be concerned: the static analysis tool is technically correct that `x` can be uninitialised, but in those cases it's not used (and hence probably shouldn't be warning you).

I'd recommend assigning `x` a default value if you're not confident, or if the actual logic is exceedingly obtuse.

Comment: Better use the C/C++ version of **or** (`||`) instead of the **binary or** operator (`|`).

Comment: @Wolf Whoops! Corrected!

Comment: Please **don't refer to short-circuiting here, because it's simply wrong**. Short-circuiting is used for boolean *expressions* and in the case shown, the only expression that is (most probably) short-circuit evaluated is `( !pre || !x || !post )`, and it is passed in 7 of 8 cases, especially in all cases where `!pre`, the point is that `x` is only evaluated if `!!pre`, in other words if `pre` is `true`.

Comment: Please have a look on the second issue as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @Wolf There's two uses of `x` in your example, one is `( !pre || !x || !post )`, the other is in the `else if` block. In the former, `!x` isn't evaluated if `!pre` (and if `!pre`, then `x` is undefined) due to short-circuiting. I agree that it isn't the "whole story" (notable `else if(!x)` which is obviously not evaluated if `!pre`), but I disagree that it's wrong outright. Unless I missed something?

Comment: @Wolf Edited to clarify that not every usage of `!x` is skipped due to short-circuiting. (I'm also aware your answer has pegged this as an issue with cppcheck in unreachable code; it's still an interesting question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120436/discussion-between-wolf-and-kidneychris).

Comment: Following an extended chat discussion, I've edited the answer to hopefully be a bit more well-rounded, and not focussed so much on a singular issue (which wasn't all that important to the problem anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It is a **false positive** in Cppcheck. I *solved* it by adding an inline suppression:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
    if ( !pre ) {
        trace("pre failed");
    // cppcheck-suppress uninitvar
    } else if ( !x ) {
        trace("x failed");
    } else {
        trace("post failed");
    }
```

and I also brought it to the attention of the Cppcheck developers:

[#7663 (False positive: uninitialised variable in unreachable code)](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/7663)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I decided not to initialize the variable. This is not for performance reasons, but to be informed about the bug being fixed in a future release, when Cppcheck will say

```
Id: unmatchedSuppression
Summary: Unmatched suppression: uninitvar
Message: Unmatched suppression: uninitvar
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `pre` condition is `false` than x will be uninitialized. At line `if ( !x )` CppCheck warns about usage of indeterminate value. To fix it initialize `x` variable.

Comment: If `pre` is `false` then `!x` is not checked due to one of short circuiting or lazy evaluation, can't remember what it is called.

Comment: I think it's not even short-circuiting, but just impossible that `x` is uninitialized if `pre` is true. Well, initializing `x` will not harm, yes.

Comment: @nwp @Wolf You right, `!x` doesn't checked in `!pre || !x || !post` in this case. But seems CppCheck doesn't have proper value propagation to understand that `if ( !x )` is also not executed. Also it's better to warn about a possible problem here, because it can cause a real problem when outer condition `!pre || !x || !post` will be changed.