# How to make C++ compiler produce error or warning when an instance variable is uninitialized?

Tags: c++, xcode, gnu

Consider this simple class

```
class A
{
 public:
    int a;
};
```

As you can see `int a` has never been initialized. I would like to get an error or at least warning in such cases. I'm using `Xcode` with `GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]` C++ dialect. Is it even possible?

UPDATE:

First of all I created an instance of `A` and used its `a` member and still received no warning:

```
A a;

std::cout << a.a;
```

Also I looked into [Easy way to find initialized member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099692/easy-way-find-uninitialized-member-variables), it suggests adding `-Weffc++` flag. I tried to add it via custom compiler flags in the Xcode Build Settings (is it a wrong way to do so? I'm not sure) and it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way find uninitialized member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099692/easy-way-find-uninitialized-member-variables)

Comment: If the member variable is uninitialized or not depends on how you initialize instances of the class. If you use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (as in `A a{123};`) then `a` *will* be initialized.

Comment: Since there are no instances of class `A` there is nothing to initialize here. Note that even though `a` is not initialized in class body it does not nessesery mean that it won't be initialized when class instances are created, for example one may write `A aa{3};`

Comment: What VTT said. GCC issues a warning if you try to create an instance of `A` and use `.a` without initializing it first: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2a20e487219a19a

Comment: You're likely using `clang` not `gcc` (`gcc` is often an alias for `clang` on OS X), which will not warn you for this kind of uninitialized member, even with all warning flags turned on.

Comment: @Holt Yes, the compiler is Clang, but the language dialect is GNU++11[-std=gnu++11] (I'm not sure how it all fits together). So you mean there's no option for me to achieve that?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha The language dialect only says that you are compiling with `-std=gnu++11`. Maybe it add other things to XCode but not to the clang compilation, so I don't think there is a way to get a warning for this using `clang`.

Comment: @Holt thanks a lot!

Comment: @Holt Yet Clang does have -Wunitialized in its warning list. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wuninitialized. Do I understand right that it cannot be enabled for c++?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha `-Wunitialized` will warn you about unitialized **variables**, e.g., `int c; std::cout << c;`, but not about unitialized **members** as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

GCC provides `-Wuninitialized` compiler option for warning about uninitialized variables.

This works for your case. See demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_NgXai).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but now my question is how to enable it in Xcode? I added this option through custom compiler flags to Other C++ flags and Other Warning Flags and it didn't work

Comment: I am not familiar with Xcode. What could be happening is that this particular option is somehow superseded by some other option. Can you try to remove all other options except `-Wuninitialized` and see if it works?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Xcode has an Uninitialized Variables build setting in the Apple Clang Warnings All languages section. If you start typing the word `uninitialized` in the search field in the build settings editor, you should be able to find it easily.